# Pass all the elements of a list through a functions

Tags: list, function, python-3.x, parameters

I created a python program that arranges and finds the median of a series of numbers a user inputs. I keep getting this error.

*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/NL-LP3/Desktop/Corses/Python/Tests Programs/median user input.py", line 24, in 
    median(^series)
TypeError: median() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given*

```
    series=[]
    finished = False
    while not finished:
        number = input("Please enter a number, when you are done hit ENTER")   
        if len(number)>0:
            series.append([number])
            print ("Number Entered")        
        else:
            finished = True

    print (series)

    def median(data):
        data.sort(key=int)
        elements = len(data)
        middle = int(elements/2)
        if elements%2 ==1:
             print (data[middle])
        else:
            half = ((data[middle])+(data[middle-1]))/2
            print (half)

    median(*series)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three issues here:

1. You are passing in a string into your array, you need to convert it to an int
2. You are passing in an array to an array which gives you an output like this:

   [[5], [6], [7]]
3. You are attempting to unpack your array by using the * in your *series.

It needs to be this:

```
[5, 6, 7]
```

Change this line:

```
series.append(int(number))
```

You are also just need to pass in the array to median like such:

```
median(series)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am a beginner at Python so it has really helped.

Answer (score 0):

you unpack your series as you are passing it to your function:

```
 median(*series)
```

this way `median` is called with all the items in the list as arguments. what you want is:

```
median(series)
```

missed the second issue! read [Jason Heine's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41725513/4954037)...